# Armadillo - matrix multiplication error

Tags: matrix-multiplication, armadillo

I'm trying to do simply matrix multiplication using Armadillo:

```
mat33 MatA, MatB, MatC;

MatA = MatB * MatC;
```

and this error occurs:

```
 C:\...SFunction.cpp:21: error: C2666: 'arma::Mat<eT>::operator =' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
    with
    [
        eT=double
    ]
    c:\...\include\armadillo\armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp(724): could be 'const arma::Mat<eT> &arma::Mat<eT>::fixed<fixed_n_rows,fixed_n_cols>::operator =(const arma::Mat<eT>::fixed<fixed_n_rows,fixed_n_cols> &)'
    with
    [
        eT=double,
        fixed_n_rows=3,
        fixed_n_cols=3
    ]
    c:\...\include\armadillo\armadillo_bits/Mat_bones.hpp(82): or       'const arma::Mat<eT> &arma::Mat<eT>::operator =(const arma::Mat<eT> &)'
    with
    [
        eT=double
    ]
    c:\...\include\armadillo\armadillo_bits/Mat_meat.hpp(4652): or       'const arma::Mat<eT> &arma::Mat<eT>::operator =<arma::mat33,arma::mat33,arma::glue_times>(const arma::Glue<T1,T2,glue_type> &)'
    with
    [
        eT=double,
        T1=arma::mat33,
        T2=arma::mat33,
        glue_type=arma::glue_times
    ]
    while trying to match the argument list '(arma::mat33, const arma::Glue<T1,T2,glue_type>)'
    with
    [
        T1=arma::mat33,
        T2=arma::mat33,
        glue_type=arma::glue_times
    ]
```

However, when I change code to this:

```
mat33 MatA, MatB, MatC;

MatA = mat33(MatB * MatC);
```

everything is fine. It is a proper way to do matrix multipication and save the result to other matrix? Or there is another, simpler way?

Comment: Looks like you're using Visual Studio, which is known to have problems with following the C++ standard. Armadillo requires a standard-conforming compiler. So you may want to use a better C++ compiler, like gcc or clang.  For windows you can get gcc from the [mingw project](http://www.mingw.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the *mat33* (fixed size)?

You could use the plain *mat* class. And in this case the multiplication is seamless

```
mat MatA(3,3), MatB(3,3), MatC(3,3); //or MatC;
// fill MatA, MatB
MatC = MatA * MatB
```